# appending selected link into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-blade

I am working on a feature that when user selects a link from for each loop, it is appended to a div, it works at this moment but instead of one link, it appends all links available. How can I solve this?

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
@foreach ($websites as $website)
<li><a class="websites disabled" href=" {{ url('website/' . $website->name) }}"> {{  $website->name }}
</a></li> @endforeach
</div>
```

Appending link:

```
$(".websites").on('click', function() {
    $(".websites").appendTo("#content-link2");
});
```

Assigning ID to each link:

```
$('#dialog li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'page'+(i+1));
});
```

Removing disabled class so `<a>` works as a link:

```
$("#addLinks").on('click', function() {
    $(".websites").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the **this** reference

```
$(".websites").on('click', function() {
  $(this).appendTo("#content-link2");
});
```

Comment: that works well, so simple. But why does it only works when I disable class "disabled"?

Comment: @Przemek i believe you have to use *this* everywhere you have on() in your code, try ;)

Comment: if you can make a jsfiddle people can help you moar @Przemek

Comment: it kind of works but I need to have e.preventDefault(); and remove it if I want the links to work, but when I remove that how can I assign it back on?

Comment: @Przemek again a jsfiddle and i can help you further ;) HOWEVER if you want to add/remove classes you have these options **addClass()** **removeClass()** **toggleClass()**

Comment: I can't really create a jsfiddle as I am using laravel blade

Comment: how does this prevent, e.preventDefault? because for some reason I need it for code to work

Comment: @Przemek man i think you better open a new question for what you asking for which is not clear to me. Accept this and open a new one ;)